# SQL PHP search LIKE two columns?

Tags: mysql

I have the below query;

```
SELECT * FROM `` WHERE `fname` LIKE 'argument' OR `lname` LIKE 'argument'
```

What do I need to change in order to 'concatenate' the columns so that I can search for rows `LIKE` `fname.lname` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want to concatenate the fields together for the `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM staff 
WHERE concat_ws(' ', fname, lname) LIKE '%".$searchq."%';
```

If the comparison could go either way, then you might want two comparisons:

```
SELECT *
FROM staff 
WHERE concat_ws(' ', fname, lname) LIKE '%".$searchq."%' or
      concat_ws(' ', lname, fname) LIKE '%".$searchq."%'
```